# How can I add a Font-Awesome icon on my form field?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome

I am making a form and I want to use [Font-Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) icon on my input field.

Here is my HTML code.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <span class="input-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
        <input class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text">
    </span>
</div>
```

I want to show the icon *on* my input field. Currently it show up *above* my input field.

Comment: When you say "on" your field, to you mean inside of the textbox / input?

Comment: What's `input-icon`?

Answer (score 5):

There are so many ways to achieve this. Follow the method below and adjust as needed.

```css
span {
  position: relative; /* Helps curtail overlap */
  border: solid 1px #bbb;
  padding: 3px 5px 5px 25px; /* Adjust as needed */
}
span input {
  border: none;
}
span:before {
  content: '\f007';
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  color: #888; /* Your desired color */
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span class="input-icon">
        <input class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text">
                        </span>
```

[See fontAwesome content value cheat sheet here.](http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/)

Answer (score 1):

make the span relative and the icon absolute positioned.

```
.input-icon {position: relative; display: inline-block;}
.input-icon .fa {position: absolute; left: -30px; top: 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using Font-Awesome and Bootstrap 3, so [use the standard pattern](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Bootstrap-Caveats#icon-placement-when-used-in-input-with-feedback).

There is a "disagreement" between Font-Awesome and Bootstrap about placement of the icon, but as the above link mentions, changing the icon `<span>` from

```
<span class="fa fa-user form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

to

```
<span class="form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
</span>
```

fixes that.